# Tricky sentence-poor knowledge-need help

Tags: meaning

> "The Contractor shall make allowance for instruction of personnel to run the works using a staffing structure equal to that of the Contractor's staffing structure for the Works".

My poor English didn't help much when this sentence appeared in a
    contract I am now studying. I think the meaning of it is " the contractor should think about showing the "personnel that is about to run the works" by using the same staffing structure they (the contractor) have already used to run the works (Works here means "the factory")

Please help me by correct my understanding if it is wrong and showing me where have I misunderstood this sentence

Answer (score 1):

It is a vague requirement indeed. Let's assume that "make allowance" means either "set aside funds to cover the cost" or "factor in the time required", as it might if this sentence appears in a section devoted to promises about delivery and "go live" dates.

The uppercase "W" in Works, if it appears in the original, is  a legal convention indicating that "Works" has been defined elsewhere in the contract.

To me, the sentence makes sense only if there are two different places being described, "the works" and "the Works".

> Contractor shall cover the cost of instructing personnel to run the
>   works,  assuming the works will have a staff equal in size and
>   structure to that of Contractor's (current) staff at the Works.
>
> Contractor shall take into account the time required to instruct
>   personnel to run the works, assuming the works will have a staff equal
>   in size and structure to that of Contractor's (current) staff at the
>   Works.